# R Show P-value results of lm as matrix

Tags: r, matrix, lm

I have a data frame containing multiple socio-economic factors with the correspondent obersvations. I want to run an lm-Analysis on all of them and then form a new matrix(or data frame) which contains all the Pvalues for each combination of variables.

My original data is in the matrix SFI.Matrix and contains 7 rows with each 12 entries.

I tried the following:
1.) build the result matrix
2.) run the lm for all of the different combinations
3.) combine those results in the result matrix.

My code looks as follows:

```
Levene.Tests.Results <- matrix(1, nr=7, nc=7)
rownames(Levene.Tests) <- colnames(Levene.Tests) <- colnames(SFI.Matrix)


for(i in 1:7) {
for(j in 1:7) {
Levene.Tests <- lm(SFI.Matrix[,i] ~ SFI.Matrix[,j])$p.value }}
```

My problem is that the result I get is a matrix [n=7,m=7]  with all NAs.

I will appreciate any advise :-)

Also, I am not really sure whether this actually works because the data entries are rates... Can you help me with this?

Comment: A few comments: (1) this seems statistically questionable.  Perhaps you just want to work with the correlations among the variables? (see `cor`, `cor.test`). (2) If you want the overall p-value for the regression as shown by `stats:::print.summary.lm()`, you probably need something like `pf(x$fstatistic[1], 
x$fstatistic[2L], x$fstatistic[3L], lower.tail = FALSE)` where `x` is the summary of your fitted model

Comment: @BenBolker your comment was very helpful! Indeed it seemed I used the wrong function. The cor-test works perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: If you were able to answer your own question, it's best if you can write up the solution and post it as an answer (it is allowed and indeed encouraged to answer your own questions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the advice of @BenBolker I was able to solve the problem. Indeed, lm was the wrong function. The correct function is the test.cor which brings very useful results:

```
Correlations<- matrix( nrow=7, ncol=7)
for(i in 1:7) {
for(j in 1:7) {
Correlations[i,j] <- cor.test( SFI.Matrix[,i], SFI.Matrix[,j] )$p.value
}
}
```

Thank you once more, Stackoverflow!